# Sharepoint BDC Error: The title property of entity tblStaff is set to an invalid value

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, business-intelligence, bdc

I am just starting to create our Business Data Catalog(s) for our practice management system and I am running into an issue w/ our staff table.

Background:

1. I am using Business Data Catalog Definition Editor to create my ADF.
2. I am using the RevertToSelf Authentication Mode.
3. I have tried a few other tables and they seem to work just fine thus far.. only issue is w/ the staff table.
4. If I removed all the columns for the staff entity except the ID and a few columns for the name it actually works.  So it has a problem w/ one of my columns in tblStaff.
5. I receive this error even when I set up an ADF w/ just this one entity.  So w/ no associations..

When attempting to view the record: http://servername/ssp/admin/Content/tblstaff.aspx?StaffID={0} w/ {0} replaced w/ an actual staff ID I get the following error:

The title property of entity tblStaff is set to an invalid value.

Things I have tried:

1. I noticed that I do have a column in my staff table called "Title" and removed it from ADF w/ no luck... Same error..
2. I tried to use bdc meta man to create my ADF and I got the same error...

Any ideas?

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Chris,
try this http://www.anthonypounder.com/blog/cns!400938DCD454D501!728.entry.

Hope it helps.

Tony